# Node js passing JSON to ejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I want to take json from the url. I am doing that with module 'request' like this

```
var request = require('request');
require('body-parser');
var each = require('foreach');

var options = {
  url: '//Some url',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var info = JSON.parse(body);
    // body.rgDescriptions.forEach(function(key, value){
    //  console.log(value.classid);
    // });

     each(info.rgDescriptions, function(item){
        console.log(item.name);
     });
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

When i am using each its working just fine, but when i try forEach its not. What i acctualy want to do is, put this function inside app.get in app.js, like this:

```
app.get('/account/:id', ensureAuthenticated, ensureID, function(req, res){
  var userItems = request('//URL', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      var info = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render('account', { 
          user: req.user,
          items: info.rgDescriptions
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Now problem is when i pass to EJS, i want to forEach this, but there is no success. I think i tried everything, but...

Here is ejs file

```
                <table>
                <% for(var i=0; i < items.length ; i++) { %>
                   <tr>
                     <td><%= items[i].name %></td>
                   </tr>
                <% } %>
                </table>
```

And when i try

```
item.forEach(function(item){
 // No success either
});
```

Comment: And what's in `info.rgDescriptions`

Comment: Sorry fot late answer, https://i.imgsafe.org/f104f79483.jpg here is the image. It is part of json

Comment: I want to forEach everything in rgDescriptions

Comment: `rgDescriptions` is an object, it has no `Array.forEach` method, that's why it doesn't work. Use a `for..in` loop instead

Comment: Yes, that work. One more question, how to access for example classid, or name inside rgDescriptions. Do i need one more for in, or?